# Trying to filter an array from a JSON file with a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

This is probably a simple thing but I'm a novice and very confused.

```
  const filteredFloors = state.cfAllFloors.json.filter(floor => {
    return floor.fields.building.fields.slug === 'Library'
  })
```

I would like to change the condition on this object to first check if the **building** exists, if it does, then check to see if it matches 'Library'.

I keep getting **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined"** and I suspect it is because some of the array items don't have this property.

Comment: The error message means that `floor.fields.building` resolves as `undefined`, therefore you cannot get the `.fields` property from it. So, check for that first, then the next fields.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. The question is how do I check whether or not the building exists first and move on to checking if the slug matches 'Library'

Comment: have you tried if(typeof floor.fields.building == "undefined")) {alert('slugs!');} https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/typeof.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const filteredFloors = state.cfAllFloors.json.filter(floor => {
    return floor && floor.fields && floor.fields.building && floor.fields.building.fields && floor.fields.building.fields.slug === 'Library'
  })
```

will return false if any of the properties in that chain are `null` or if the final `.slug` is not equal to 'Library'.

A `null` value is not "truthy" and thus checking the object will return false if it is `null` or `true` if it has any value.

Comment: How do I create the condition to determine if it "truthy" then check to see if it matches the slug?

Comment: Just like the code I posted, you can `and` your conditions together so, for example `return bob && bob = "myname";` would return `true` if `bob = "myname"` but would return false if it equals some other string, or if `bob` is `null`.

Comment: scroll the code I posted in the answer all the way to the right, you will see that the final `&&` condition is your original string check.

Comment: If any of the preceding objects in that chain are `null` it will never get to the string check, but will return `false`, it will only continue to the end of the chain and check the string value if all preceding objects evaluated "truthy" because they were non-null.

Comment: doh! I see! Thank you and for your patience!